# visual studio 2008 regions equivalent for javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008

visual studio 2008 allows c# code to be segregated into regions 
is there an equivalent for javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Javascript don't support this.
You can do the separation by comments.

```
/*My Region (Name It)*/
your scripts
/*End Region*/
```

Or you can see this thread how to do it.
[how to implement regions/code collapse in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921628/how-to-implement-regions-code-collapse-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to do this in VS2008: highlight the section of code you want to collapse, then press the `Ctrl-M+H` chord.

I use this quite a bit when editing javascript files, but unfortunately it isn't permanent - the javascript code will be back to its regular self if you close and reopen the file. I've had js files open for weeks at a time in the editor in the past, simply to avoid losing all my carefully crafted collapsible regions.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can collapse custom code sections in Dreamweaver, might be worth editing your JavaScript using that instead