# Regions/code collapse in Javascript in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, code-regions

Is it possible to create code regions in JS files in Visual Studio 2010?

[This method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921628/how-to-implement-regions-code-collapse-in-javascript) works in 2005, but I can't get working in 2010.

Comment: Try it, if the compiler throws you an error, then it obviously won't work. ;)

Comment: I have. I actually got stuck at adding a keyboard shortcut to the macro. I've never used VS macros before so am probably doing something silly. The macro doesn't seem to appear in the list when I try and assign a keyboard shortcut to it. Have you any idea why that would happen?

Comment: Oh, Type "macros" in the search box. It'll auto-show all macros. Here's the full tutorial on this: http://blog.devarchive.net/2008/04/using-region-directive-with-javascript.html

Comment: Cheers Zack. I followed that tutorial. No idea why the macro doesn't show up.

Comment: Is it still not showing up? :\

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here is a very cool VS2010 extension for Javascript and CSS outlining
http://jsoutlining.codeplex.com/

Comment: Microsoft now has an extension for VS2010 that provides this functionality (see my answer below for link).

Answer (score 33):

Microsoft now has an extension for VS2010 that provides this functionality:

[JScript Editor Extensions](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/872d27ee-38c7-4a97-98dc-0d8a431cc2ed?SRC=VSIDE)

Comment: @BrianFinkel How do I create regions using the JScriptEditor Extensions?

Comment: That's a good question.  I'm not sure.  Will let you know if I find out.

Comment: Amazing...JS files can become very difficult to read through but this make it more manageable!!

Comment: I installed it, but it significantly increased the save time of my ASPX pages.  I had to disable.

Comment: I have not had that problem.  Do you have a large amount of JavaScript in your ASPX pages?

Comment: @Nick What works for me is to add a comment for the name of the section like //MySection and then add brackets {} with the code in between.

Answer (score 1):

The [JSEnhancements](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0696ad60-1c68-4b2a-9646-4b5f4f8f2e06) plugin for Visual Studio addresses this nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Advanced JavaScript Outlining for Visual Studio 11 is now available for VS2012 through the Extension Manger, or at the URL

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4be701d8-af03-40a4-8cdc-d2add5cde46c?SRC=VSIDE

Answer (score 0):

There's an interesting post here : http://blog.devarchive.net/2008/04/using-region-directive-with-javascript.html on how to do this using Macros in Visual Studio.

Hope that help.

**Update**
I just realised that someone has already referenced this link in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Another great Visual Studio 2012-Extension is Web Essentials 2012.
There are a bunch of cool tools for even TypeScript, LESS and CoffeeScript.

http://vswebessentials.com/

Answer (score 0):

Even though VS extensions installed, I had a unique problem of some of the script blocks not outlining properly, later found that its because of the **@Url.Content** tag used in the script, simply replaced it with simple string url, the outlining worked....thought of sharing if it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2015 you can just create a block around your "region" like this

```
{ //My little region
  function misc()...
  var x = '';
  //etc...
  ...
}
```

Then just collapse that block. Probably on all older versions of Visual Studio as well.