# HLSL (.fx file) Syntax Highlighting in VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, syntax, hlsl

Is there any way to get syntax highlighting (and maybe something like "Format Document") for fx files in visual studio 2010 ? It is quite hard to debug more complex HLSL shader code without it. I know I could use fx composer but I would rather not switch between different dev-environments :-) Furthermore, I frequently use #region pragmas in VS2010. Is there something similar for editing HLSL shader code in VS2010?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a look to the [NShader project on CodePlex](http://nshader.codeplex.com/). It's an extension for Visual Studio 2010 that does just that: adding syntax highlighting for various shading languages.

Regarding the `#region` pragmas, I think that a macro, as explained in [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1921636/1374267), will do the trick. [Here is another example](http://www.kynosarges.org/RegionTools.html) also.

Comment: Great, this seems to work nicely. Is there any equivalent for the region pragma?

Comment: Glad to help! I've edited my answer concerning the `#region` pragmas.

Comment: @Yannik: Thank! However, both plugins in that answer seem to not work with *.fx files but only with *.js files, do they?

Comment: @pad_ares As comments are formatted the same way in HLSL and JS, the first macro should work with your `*.fx` files. You will have to use `//#region` instead of `#region` though.