# How to add region in java script file, visual studio

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to add region to collapse and expand code in java script. If any body knows solution, it will be great. thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to implement regions/code collapse in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921628/how-to-implement-regions-code-collapse-in-javascript)

Comment: Regions are usually editor dependent, not a language feature. Some developers argue that the concept of regions are inherently bad, since they promote hiding ugly code, when you ought to just structure your code properly so regions aren't necessary.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

It depends only on the **IDE**.

**vscode**, for example, added support for code regions in september 2017

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_17#_folding-regions

For **javascript**:

```
//#region

code

//#endregion
```

or

```
//region

and

//endregion
```

The same syntax could work also in different IDEs.

Comment: I thought it still doesn't supported except C#.

Comment: //#region...endregion is worked for me

Comment: the exact syntax is `// #region custom_region_name`, see curiousBoy's answer that should be the accepted answer

Comment: @MAMYSébastien it depends on the IDE implementation and the language used. See the link for vscode provided as example in the answer.

Comment: `//region` did not work for me, but `//#region` did. VSCode v1.85.2.

Answer (score 37):

This works great on Visual Studio 2017 ( I haven't tried with other versions)

[Java Script Regions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.JavaScriptRegions)

[image]

[JavaScriptRegions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8Hhf.png)

[image: Screen shot for outlining]

[image]

Comment: Work in VS2019 without installing any plugin as far as I am aware.

Comment: Works in VS Code 

Comment: Still good in 2022 - much better than the braces I was using before!

Answer (score 4):

for older version(vs2015 and below) select your code block => press CTRL + M+H The Code Will be collapsible